# How to convert a ruby hash into a string with a specific format

Tags: ruby

This is the hash I'm trying to format

```
input = {"test_key"=>"test_value", "test_key2"=>"test_value2"}
```

And this is the expected result

```
"{\n\t\"test_key\" = \"test_value\";\n\t\"test_key2\" = \"test_value2\";\n}"
```

I have the following code so far

```
def format_hash(hash)
  output = ""
  hash.to_s.split(',').each do |k|
    new_string = k + ';'
    new_string.gsub!('=>', ' = ')
    output += new_string
  end
end
```

which gives me the this output

```
output = "{\"test_key\" = \"test_value\"; \"test_key2\" = \"test_value2\"};"
```

But I'm still struggling with adding the rest. Any ideas/suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
input = {"test_key"=>"test_value", "test_key2"=>"test_value2"}
```

```
"{" << input.map { |k,v| "\n\t\"#{k}\" = \"#{v}\"" }.join(';') << ";\n}"
  #=> "{\n\t\"test_key\" = \"test_value\";\n\t\"test_key2\" = \"test_value2\";\n}"
```

The steps are as follows.

```
a = input.map { |k,v| "\n\t\"#{k}\" = \"#{v}\"" }
  #=> ["\n\t\"test_key\" = \"test_value\"", "\n\t\"test_key2\" = \"test_value2\""] 
b = a.join(';')
  #=> "\n\t\"test_key\" = \"test_value\";\n\t\"test_key2\" = \"test_value2\""
"{" << b << ";\n}"
  #=> "{\n\t\"test_key\" = \"test_value\";\n\t\"test_key2\" = \"test_value2\";\n}"
```

`input` may contain any number of key-value pairs that adhere to the indicated pattern.

Comment: Any idea why I'm getting the `+` signs in the output? I'm using the rails console
`"{\n" + "\t\"test_key\" = \"test_value\";\n" + "\t\"test_key2\" = \"test_value2\";\n" + "}"`

Comment: Are you sure you aren't looking at what you entered rather than the return value? Since you tried that I changed `+` to `<<` to make it slightly more efficient. Please try again with the current version. Also, confirm `input` has the correct value.

Comment: Thanks for the greenie but it's best to wait awhile, mainly to avoid discouraging other readers from posting answers, but also to allow readers still working on their answers to complete them. Most here wait at least a couple of hours before making a selection; some wait until then-sleeping readers around the world have tuned into SO. There's no rush. Feel free to retract the checkmark if you wish to do so.

Answer (score 1):

One starting point might be to use JSON formatter:

```
require 'json'
input = {"test_key"=>"test_value", "test_key2"=>"test_value2"}
JSON.pretty_generate(input)

=> "{\n  \"test_key\": \"test_value\",\n  \"test_key2\": \"test_value2\"\n}"
```

This has some subtle differences, since it looks like you use `=` as opposed to `:`.  That said, perhaps it's easier to work from this than from what you have.

#### Working with JSON

```
JSON.pretty_generate(input).gsub(/:/,' =').gsub(/,(?=\n)/, ';').gsub(/(;\n|\n)\s+/, '\1'+"\t")

=> "{\n\t\"test_key\" = \"test_value\";\n\t\"test_key2\" = \"test_value2\"\n}"
```

#### Custom Formatter

Of course you could define your custom formatter:

```
def formatter(hash)
  output = ""
  output += "{\n\t" 
  output += hash.entries.map{|a| "\"#{a[0]}\" = \"#{a[1]}\"" }.join(";\n\t")
  output += ";\n}"
end

formatter( input )
```